# Apache Wicket and jQuery JavaScript in head section only loaded once

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, wicket

I face some strange issues when integrating jQuery with Wicket.

We load each content item as Panel in Wicket using Ajax. So it is a Single Page Application.

In the header of the Panel we add some JS, for example:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function() {
            $('#example').dataTable( {
                "sScrollY": "200px",
                "bPaginate": false
            } );
        } );
    </script>
```

However this code seems to be executed only the first time the Panel is loaded. If you reload the Panel into the application using Ajax, the code is not executed anymore.

I guess JS $(document).ready is only initialized one time, the second time you load the same JS into the browser $(document).ready is no more called.

Is there a workaround with Wicket for that issue?

Thanks!

Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issues given on this answer: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/wicket-users/201209.mbox/%3CCAAJwaYUSfoFZHVP4EXSxuw_Co-J0W6qvV1MR8wGERjfNzj2CxA%40mail.gmail.com%3E

Answer (score 1):

document ready gets called only once, if you want to call on every load write the code as a seperate method and call it on success of every ajax load

Comment: yes I know, but the question is how to invoke a JavaScript method in Wicket when Ajax load is complete.

Comment: Isn't AjaxRequestTarget.appendJavaScript(CharSequence javascript) suited for your task?

Comment: see below an example. You are right, however it is not that easy, you also have to add it in the head section to make it working.

Answer (score 0):

You could add Renderhead().It executes whatever is being written inside it even on page refresh